# Filtering using an HTTP request

Tags: python, api, rest

I'm currently using the XT.com API (crypto currency exchange).
I would like to get the latest price of a crypto currency on this exchange. Below is my code so far :

```
ticker = api.get_ticker(dict(market='btc_usdt'))
#XTPrice = ticker['price']
print(ticker)
```

Running this code gives me this :

```
Please wait a moment...retry now... times is 1
(True, {'high': 50494.6, 'low': 47993.99, 'rate': 0.0267, 'price': 50174.41, 'moneyVol': 40012402.49752388, 'coinVol': 809.706147, 'ask': 50173.88, 'bid': 50172.19, 'askVol': 0.147934, 'bidVol': 0.052413, 'depthTime': 1629726830489}, <Response [200]>)
```

I would like to keep only the 'price' part. I have tried to add the code:

```
XTPrice = ticker['price']
print(XTPrice)
```

But this results in an error.

Could anyone please provide me with any help ?

Comment: `ticker[1]['price']`

Comment: You should probably understand why too.
You have a tuple of 3 items. A tuple is an ordered list of objects.
In your tuple you have a boolean, then a dict, then a Response instance.
`Tuple(bool, dict, Response)`
You can pull out of the tuple using an index like with a list, hence why `[1]` is needed before `['price']`

Comment: Ok I got it now, thanks. If I well understood, print(ticker[0]) would return "True", and ticker[2] --> <Response [200]> ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ticker[1]['price']
```

*code provided by Epsi95*